# Extract required string from a string

Tags: ios, nsstring

Hey i am new to ios I want to get part of string from a string,

the original string is,

OriginalString=@"access_token=CAAEW97M253kB2BZBg9VysMCkOyjDi6HtvLcqtkh3Xp5y4ZBZCExq8ZCCZCKo2QZAJ8lSQ9EvOhtPPxr0pLM5NgNE5jFC1blzn8tu0xhvOcXIn&expires=5178989";

i want to get "&expires=5178989" this.

Answer (score 0):

If it will always be this format, you can can do:

```
NSArray *components = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
```

Your string will be the second object. Retrieve it with:

```
NSSTring *expires = [components lastObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)extractString:(NSString *)fullString toLookFor:(NSString *)lookFor skipForwardX:(NSInteger)skipForward toStopBefore:(NSString *)stopBefore 
{

    NSRange firstRange = [fullString rangeOfString:lookFor];
    NSRange secondRange = [[fullString substringFromIndex:firstRange.location + skipForward] rangeOfString:stopBefore];
    NSRange finalRange = NSMakeRange(firstRange.location + skipForward, secondRange.location + [stopBefore length]);

    return [fullString substringWithRange:finalRange];
}
```

call this function like this

```
NSString *strTemp = [self extractString:@"abcdefwww.google.comabcdef" toLookFor:@"www" skipForwardX:0 toStopBefore:@".com"];
NSLog(@"\n\n Substring ==>> %@",strTemp);
```